# Another Android Activity or an iterative JAVA method?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am new to Android application development and am trying to find a way to proceed through a series of screens that take in user input.  I'm making a small math game where the user would answer basic two integer addition problems. So far the main menu is created.  It has a New Game button which launches my GameActivity and it runs just fine for one math problem.  However, after the user inputs their answer to the simple math problem, I would like to be able to continue on to another math problem once the user had answered the current problem and the method would return a correct/incorrect value. Initially I thought of doing something like a basic FOR loop from within the GameActivity :

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ gameMethod(); }
```

gameMethod() is a JAVA method that simply generates 2 random numbers, adds them to get the correct answer and then prompts the user using an EditText field to type in their guess.  It displays the random numbers and answer using TextView boxes created in an XML layout file.

Each call to the gameMethod would, at least I think, just re-input the randomized numbers into the TextView fields displayed on the screen each iteration.  I really don't care what the previous numbers were so I figured I would just overwrite them.  I wan't able to get the code to do that though.  I put in a Log.d() statement or two and found that the FOR loop was in fact running through correctly 10 times, but it was not waiting for user input before firing off its next gameMethod().

In doing some looking around, I found the startActivityForResult() and wondered if this was a more appropriate way of approaching this.  So in this way, I foresee having three Activities, the Main menu which calls the GameActivity which would then iterate through, say 10 times, each iteration calling yet another activity GameScreenActivity which would actually put the numbers on the screen, read in user input and then return 1 for a correct answer and 0 for an incorrect answer.  So far in reading up on StarActivityForResult() I'm getting somewhat confused by the process and wondered if this was even a plausible path to be exploring.

Again, I'm very new at this Android programming and appreciate any and all help that I can get.

Thank you.

Sorry for not including the gameMethod() initially, I've added it below.

```
// Create and initialize arrays of integers
    int[] a = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int[] b = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    // Creates random number generator
    Random randy = new Random();

    // Generates two random values to add
    int r1 = randy.nextInt(10);
    int r2 = randy.nextInt(10);

    // Calculates correct answer
    int an = a[r1] + a[r2]; 

    // Displays 1st number
    TextView number1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstNumber);
    number1.setText(Integer.toString(a[r1]));

    // Displays 2nd number 
    TextView number2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secondNumber);
    number2.setText(Integer.toString(b[r2]));

    // Displays correct answer 
    TextView answer1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerNumber);

    //hide answer until user puts in theirs
    answer1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    answer1.setText(Integer.toString(an));

    //hide the answer place holder value
    TextView uAnswerDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userAnswerNumber);
    uAnswerDisplay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //Get the EditText field that the user will input their answer to
    EditText inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userInput);

    //set up a listener to run once the ENTER key is hit after their answer has been entered
    inputText.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener(){
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){

    //only go on the ENTER key when pressed DOWN
    if((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
          (keyCode ==  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){

    EditText innerInputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userInput); //get the EditText box reference
                TextView innerUAnswerDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userAnswerNumber); //get the TextView box that the answer will go in
                String inputString = innerInputText.getText().toString(); //capture the user's input

                int uAnswer = Integer.parseInt(inputString); //parse user answer to an integer
                int cAnswer = Integer.parseInt((((TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerNumber)).getText()).toString());
                innerUAnswerDisplay.setText(Integer.toString(uAnswer)); //display the string after converting from integer

                //change colors of text based on correctness
                if (uAnswer == cAnswer){ innerUAnswerDisplay.setTextColor(Color.GREEN); } //green for correct
                else { innerUAnswerDisplay.setTextColor(Color.RED); } //red for incorrect

                innerUAnswerDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //make the user input answer visible

                TextView innerAnswer1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerNumber);
                innerAnswer1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //hide answer until user puts in theirs
            } //end of if
            return false; //return false 
        } //end of onKey

    }); //end of setOnKeyListener
```

Sorry for all the edits, I couldn't get the edits to include the code and post correctly so I broke it up into chunks and added a little at a time.

Comment: You say that "gameMethod" prompts the user for an answer. It would help if you give us the code that prompts the user. A "prompt" generally only happens when you start an activity, fragment, dialog or dialogfragment, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

From what you say, I'd consider two ways of letting the user answer questions:

1. have an onclick listener on the input EditText that triggers a new loop;
2. have a dialog activity that gets started in the beginning of the loop, which prompts the user for a new answer, your game activity would receive the answer via its onActivityResult.